# E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1

Tags: 12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Dell power-edge R720 server, facing the problem when I

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic-pae (3.2.0-37.58) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-37-generic-pae
 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic-pae

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic-pae with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0
-37-generic-pae.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------------
even i tried with apt-get clean
apt-get remove
apt-get autoremove
apt-get purge
there is no difference it will show the same error message as above,
even i checked the disk space
-----------
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       24030076    612456  22196964   3% /
udev            16536644         4  16536640   1% /dev
tmpfs            6618884      1164   6617720   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none            16547208        72  16547136   1% /run/shm
cgroup          16547208         0  16547208   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          93207     75034     13361  85% /boot
/dev/sda10       9611492   1096076   8027176  13% /tmp
/dev/sda12       9611492    226340   8896912   3% /opt
/dev/sda13       9611492    152516   8970736   2% /srv
/dev/sda7        9611492    592208   8531044   7% /home
/dev/sda8        9611492   2656736   6466516  30% /usr
/dev/sda9        9611492    696468   8426784   8% /var
/dev/sda14     961237336 134563516 777845764  15% /usr/data
/dev/sda15     618991384  84498388 503050052  15% /usr/data1
/dev/sda11       9611492    152616   8970636   2% /usr/local
---------------
```

is there any problem on allotting the space to the partiations
please let me know the solution
its on urgent

please help me on this issue
regards

Comment: The error says it all: `No space left on device`. Your /boot partition only has 13MB free. Either you need to remove older kernels (if not needed) or you need to increase that partition size.

Answer (score 9):

just running:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

solved my problem

related:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) for removing old kernel images.

To rebuild the initial ram disks for the remaining kernels (ensuring that everyone has one properly built) run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```